# Web Audio Player-Recorder in React

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, web-audio-api, mediastream, mediarecorder-api

I just followed this tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/building-audio-player-react/ to create a Web Audio Player in React.

I wonder how I could add a recording functionality, so that the user could record his own voice and then play it back like any of the other songs.

What would be the best way to go in order to keep the same design and ideas already used in the app?